# Allow a user to run an instant flow without the ability to modify it

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, administration, flow, power-platform

As an admin I created 2 flows inside a solution:

1. Scheduled flow which runs on schedule basis.
2. Instant flow which is called from the Scheduled flow

Now the Schedule flow will call the instant flow on daily bases >> send 2 parameters to the instant flow >> and the instant flow will then email the project manager. the project manager review the email info and can Approve or Reject. In-case of rejection, we want the Project manager to be able to manually run the instant flow and manually pass 2 parameters.

So my question is what permissions we need to grant the Project manager on the instant flow, so he can manually run the instant flow but can not modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant **Run only users** permissions to Project manager so that they can run the instant flow manually.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to flow details page
2. Click on **Edit** next to Run only users section:

   [image]
3. Invite users or groups and click **Save** at the bottom of panel:

   [image]

**Related documentation**: [Manage owners and users in your Microsoft list flows with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-flows)

Comment: thanks a lot for the useful reply, it worked for me on the default environment. now we have this solution imported inside a production environment, so what permission we need to grant the Project manager inside the production environment?  can you advice please?

Comment: Try granting **Basic User** role for project manager in new environment.

Comment: thanks for the reply, ok will try t now, but does Basic User allow the user to delete or edit others solutions, power apps & power automate?

Comment: Basic User role has these Database privileges - Read (self), Create (self), Write (self), Delete (self). So, they should not be able to delete solutions of other users.

Comment: now in our case the environment we are planning to build will contain connection to sharepoint, Power apps and power automate.. so should this environment has a CDS ?

Comment: If you create a production type environment with database, it will have CDS/Dataverse? Check this for types of environments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environments-overview

Comment: yes i mean do i need to have a Dataverse CDS for our environment which only contain connection to sharepoint, power apps and power automate?

Comment: If you want to use solutions, you will need Dataverse. For simple integration with SharePoint using individual standalone apps/SharePoint list form customization and flows, you don't need it.

Comment: yes we will need solution of course .. but those solution will only contain Power Apps, Power Automate an connection to sharepoint.. can you advice further please?