# What are the needed steps if we want a user to be able to acces a Production Enviroment to ONLY Run an instant flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, administration, powerapp

We have created a new Production Environment which should contain all of our production solutions that contain Power Apps & Power Automate & connection to SharePoint lists/libraries.

Now we have a solution which contain an instant flow >> and we want to grant a user the ability to Run-Only the instant workflow. I know that inside the instant flow I can define the user inside the "Manage run-only permission", to be able to run the flow without the ability to modify it:

[image]

but my question is, since this instant flow is inside a solution which is inside the production environment. So what type of access (minimal access) this user needs to have on the production environment? which only allow him to run the flow and without the ability to create new power apps, power automate or solutions inside the environment?

Any help and advice please?

Comment: Try granting **Basic User** role in environment for user and then share flow as run only user. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Grant **Basic User** role in new environment for users
2. Share flow as run only user as mentioned here: [Allow a user to run an instant flow without the ability to modify it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307729/allow-a-user-to-run-an-instant-flow-without-the-ability-to-modify-it/307743#307743)

I did a test from my end and it worked for me:

[image]

**Note**:

1. After adding Basic User role in environment to user, it may take few hours to show up the environment for users.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so to be able to grant a user Basic User role in the environment , should the environment has a dataverse CDS ? or i can create an environment without dataverse CDS and be able to assign "Basic User" role? Thanks